# Is there are way to get and test Volta?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am using Google's GWT Framework however I want to try out Microsoft Volta, but I believe the server is down already.

- Was Volta release to be download and installed with Visual Studio?
- If so, has anyone have downloaded a copy of it?

Google Web Toolkit (GWT): http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/

Comment: Spell stuff out, don't use abbreviations for uncommon programs (and anything where is website is down is definitely uncommon), describe what you're trying to do so people can offer alternatives.

Comment: @xybreak : 11 Answers accepted out of 35 eligible questions. And only 7 vote casts. Not impressive! I didn't downvote for this question though.

Comment: You might want to provide a link to GWT and maybe a description of it.

Comment: @John, ok sorry about it, I just thought that those people who knew Volta knows about GWT, because searching Volta using Google shows results comparing Volta with existing GWT framework.

Comment: @xybreak : People who answer your questions expect their answers would mark as the answer or upvote if they are helpful.

Comment: @CharithJ yes I know that. Anyway guys please stop attack me for this simple question.

Comment: @xybrek: it's not common - its expected! It's a small **thank you** for the guys helping you out and it helps seeing that your question has allready been answerwed and considered *done*

Comment: @Carsten, I don't want to start an argument just for this question I have. FYI, I can say that I have thanked  a lot of people here and somehow managed to help some too. Let's stop this already as I have edited my question.

Comment: @Ben - "don't use abbreviations for uncommon programs" GWT = Google Web Toolkit, not an uncommon program at all. Maybe in the Microsoft world but not in the Java world

Comment: @Robert: Did you look at the tags?  I see `c#` and `visual-studio`, but not `java`.  But it's really "Volta" that's the problem, he should have said "Microsoft Volta C#-to-JavaScript converter" or something like that.  Because I know that's not among the [top google hits for "volta"](http://www.google.com/#q=volta), and even among ["volta software"](http://www.google.com/#q=volta+software) the audio plugin is equally likely to be discussed on SO.

Comment: @Ben - Looking at tags isn't a great argument, especially since the body talks about GWT which is Java. A (Google search for "Microsoft Volta")[http://www.google.com/search?q=microsoft+volta&rls=com.microsoft:en-za&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&startIndex=&startPage=1] does show the exact right thing. Also if you know GWT, then it is very clear what Volta he is refering to. Really reads clearly he wants the Microsoft version of GWT, aka Volta.

Comment: @Robert: There's nothing in the question to suggest that Volta is a Microsoft product.  That's why it's important to say "Microsoft Volta". And tags determine your audience... most people who regularly read `c#` and `visual-studio` tags have no idea what GWT or Microsoft Volta do.  The original question didn't even contain any hint that it's related to web applications.

Comment: @Ben - I see your point & it is valid for those without the knowledge. I do think that GWT is big enough & Volta was hyped enough in it's day that your statement is too broadly generalised and that I think many people will know those. I read the tags and knew what they were and I don't think myself special

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a link to download it here:
http://download.cnet.com/Volta/3000-2212_4-10778819.html

Answer (score 3):

I believe that [Microsoft Visual Studio LightSwitch 2011](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/lightswitch) is a development of the Volta ideas, and yes, it's available.

Comment: Too bad, I was really looking for Volta, I saw some blogs and quite impressed that it builds on similar approach as GWT, is LightSwitch similar to this? I believe Volta is about building web application using the familiar Object-oriented .NET languages, similar to GWT's Java-to-Javscript approach.

Comment: Lightswitch is also about not having to worry whether your code will execute client-side or server-side.

Comment: thanks I am not sure if I can try out LightSwitch, however I am still looking forward if someone have a copy of Volta. Which I think is not easy to find here.

Answer (score 2):

Volta was a Microsoft project to do a [C# to JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Microsoft_codenames#Others) compiler, similar to Coffee Script and GWT. Many features were added to make the development of RIA applications easier, once again very similar to GWT however it was ultimately stopped. Volta did build on top of Visual Studio.

Lightswitch is a similar concept except does not include the C# to JavaScript compiler (it uses normal C# in the app and compiles it), it produces GUI's built in Silverlight (rather than AJAX/HTML/JavaScript that Volta did) and the scope is vastly different.

Oh, I don't have a copy of Volta.